# Angular2 set condition for html

Tags: angular2-template

I'm try do make a route using for 2 difference user roles. There 2 UI for each. (I'm using `expressjs` for server)
For student `student-dashboard.html`
For teacher `teacher-dashboard.html`
The route is `example.com/dashboard`
I try this but it not working:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: user_type == 1 ?'./teacher-dashboard.html':'./student-dashboard.html'
})
```

Another ways i think:
1. make 2 `angular app`( will have 2 `dist folder`)
2. put 2 `UI` in 1 file and use `ngIf` to check.

Which one is a good solution? Many thanks

Comment: Why you are not using different component?

Comment: that great, should I choose which component is loaded in `.html` file or in `.ts` file

Comment: im looking it. Where you decide which component will be loaded

Comment: thanks for advice, but your example doesn't meet my requirement. I want use only 1 url for 2 two views(user or teacher). I will use ngIf for decide which component will be showed